# How to implement HTML5 WEB-Socket with multiple sends (requests)

Tags: html, sockets, websocket

I have a web socket service that I need it to fetch multiple requests.
I init the web socket with a url and need to send about 200 json requests.
So my question is,

**What is the best way to do it?**

Do I need open a web socket separatelly for each request?
CODE:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("wss://api.example.com/api/");

ws.onopen = function() {
    ws.send(
        JSON.stringify({
            "method": "getItem",
            "params": {
                "color": "WHITE"
            }
        })
    );
};

ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
    var received_msg = evt.data;
    console.log(received_msg);
};
```

So in this example I need more 200 times this JSON request:

```
JSON.stringify({
    "method": "getItem",
    "params": {
        "color": "WHITE"
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider adding a message queue (this could be a simple Array) and sending the messages in the queue whenever you can.

i.e.:

```
ws.queue = []

ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
    var received_msg = evt.data;
    console.log(received_msg);
    while(evt.target.queue.length) {
       evt.target.send(evt.target.queue.pop());
    }
};

ws.onopen = function(evt) {
    while(evt.target.queue.length) {
       evt.target.send(evt.target.queue.pop());
    }
}
ws.queue.push( JSON.stringify({
    "method": "getItem",
    "params": {
        "color": "WHITE"
    }
}) );
```

This is quick and dirty example, but I'm sure a similar approach could work.